# SharedPreferences changing one variable affect others as well in Android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have a very weird problem. And I spend 3-4 hours correcting as well as googling for solutions but nothing. I am storing a variable in "QuestionAsked" string but don't know why all other strings show same values.

i.e. if "QuestionAsked" was 40 and `RecordQuestionAsked()` was called, now not only "QuestionAsked" but all other even strings "xyz" created after this call, will show 41. :( What could be the problem?

```
private void RecordQuestionAsked(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int prev = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.QuestionAsked),0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putInt(getString(R.string.QuestionAsked), prev+1);
        editor.commit();
}

if (id == R.id.menuProg) {
            if(ll1.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE) {
                ll1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ll3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                int ca = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.xyz),1);
                int qa = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.QuestionAsked),0);
                pba.setProgress(ca/qa*100);
                pbi.setProgress((qa-ca)/qa*100);
                txtProg.setText("Correct Answers / Total Questions : " + ca + "/" + qa );
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that posting questions here is useless :(

However, after banging my head for 3-4 days, instead of getString(R.string.xyz), "xyz" for both get and put worked for me if anybody is interested.